# Is it possible to calculate a meaningful z-score between two values?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I have to calculate z-scores as a quality assurance test for replicate pairs of field data (water chemistry samples). I've tried processing this a handful of ways but continue to come up with 1/sqrt(2) for any pair. I did a quick derivation and it seems to me that the definition of a z-score between two samples is 1/sqrt(2) since it is normalizing the standard deviation but it's been a while since I've thought about this. I feel like this question would have come up previously but I can't find anything on it. Thanks for any help!